# Postback for the second time from asp.net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post, postback, actionmethod

**Setup:**
I am working on `reset password` page and planning to have a single view to display three forms one after another.

Initially user will be asked to enter username, then the form gets submitted.
I am able to capture it is `HttpPost` action method.

I am returning the same view but this time I am rendering a different form, I am doing this using `Razor`

When I try to submit **(calling a different action method)** from the second form that I am displaying now I am getting and error saying that **Resource cannot be found**

**Question:**
Is it not possible to post back twice from the sample page/view?
If possible how can I achieve it?

CSHTML:

```
@if (ViewBag.step == 1) {
  <form id="frmUsername" action="@Url.Content("~/Account/ValidateAnswers")" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" ng-init="initStep1()">
    ...
  </form>
}

@if (ViewBag.step == 2) {
  <form action="@Url.Content("~/Account/ValidateUsername")" id="frmQuestions" ng-init="initStep2()" novalidate="novalidate">
    ...
  </form>
}
```

Controller methods:

```
public ActionResult RecoverPassword(string userType)
{
   ViewBag.step = 1;
   ViewBag.userType = userType;
   ViewBag.showUsernameErrorMessage = "false";
   return View();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateUsername(string userName, string selectedUserType)
{
  ...
  ViewBag.step = responseStep;
  ViewBag.showUsernameErrorMessage = responseShowUsernameErrorMessage;
  ViewBag.userName = userName;
  ViewBag.userType = selectedUserType;
  return View("~/Views/Account/RecoverPassword.cshtml");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateAnswers(string answer1, string answer2, string answer3, string questionId1, string questionId2, string questionId3, string step, string userName, string selectedUserType)
{
  ...
  ViewBag.step = responseStep;
  ViewBag.showUsernameErrorMessage = responseShowUsernameErrorMessage;
  ViewBag.userName = userName;
  ViewBag.userType = selectedUserType;
  return View("~/Views/Account/RecoverPassword.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: It is possible. you need to show how are you doing that?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad question edited!

Comment: In 2nd form you are not specifying form method post, due to which it is failing